# Get Verbose Output From Command

Tags: bash, osascript

I am executing this (on a Mac):

```
find "/Volumes/Untitled3/Done" -type f -size +1400000k -exec mv -fv "{}" "/Volumes/Media/Overflow/" \;
```

When running the script in the foreground, progress is echoed to the console. As the files are quite large, it takes a while to complete, so I run it in the background (from the Scripts menu) and want to add notifications to show progress (using AppleScript via osascript):

```
osascript -e 'display notification theFile & " copied"'
```

(where `theFile` would be the output)

Is there a way that I can incorporate this into the `-exec mv`? (I appreciate that I can redirect all the output and grab it when the mv has completed, but at that point the script has finished - so it defeats the purpose.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find -exec with multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119946/find-exec-with-multiple-commands). Try `find ... -exec osascript ... \; -exec mv ... \;`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/23923167/6770384.

Comment: Thanks. The first one explained what I needed.